# How to fetch Reminder with CalendarIdentifier in EventKit?

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

in Apple Documentation
Search with Unique Identifiers

> If you know the event’s unique identifier because you fetched it previously with a predicate, you can use the EKEventStore method event(withIdentifier:) to fetch the event. If it is a recurring event, this method will return the first occurrence of the event. You can get an event’s unique identifier with the eventIdentifier property.
>
> Similarly, if you know a specific reminder’s unique identifier from previously fetching it with a predicate, you can call the **calendarItem(withIdentifier:)** instance method. **calendarItem(withIdentifier:)** can fetch any calendar item (reminders and events), whereas event(withIdentifier:) fetches only events.

My problem is I want fetch A EKReminder to use `isCompleted` property.

```
 // Mark reminder as completed
 // Use the completed property to mark a reminder as completed
 func complete(_ reminder: EKReminder) {
    reminder.isCompleted = true
    
    /* Some my customize code */
    
    // Update the reminder
    self.save(reminder)
}
```

but
method `func calendarItem(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> EKCalendarItem?` return an EKCalendarItem.

I dont want use for loop to search exactly Reminder I wanted.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EKCalendarItem` is the base class of `EKReminder` and `EKEvent`. If you know that the calendar item is a reminder cast it to `EKReminder`

```
let reminder = store.calendarItem(withIdentifier: identifier) as! EKReminder
```